# Iterate through every row in 3 tables in one foreach loop - PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach

I've got 3 tables called `comments`, `post`, `feedback`.

In a profile page, a user can see someone's activity. So for instance, if they make a comment and a post, they can see something like

`8:00 AM John has commented on this thread. 
9:00 PM Jack has posted a new post`.

The problem is that I don't know how can I combine all these records in one foreach loop.

My foreach loop right now is simply:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo 'User has made a new post: ' . $post->post;
}

foreach ($feedback as $feed) {
    echo 'User has given a new feedback: ' . $feedback->feedback;
}

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo 'User has made a new comment: ' . $comment->comment;
}
```

As you can see I have got 3 `foreach` loops. I want something like

```
foreach ($activities as $activity) {
    if ($activity->type == 'comment')
        echo "User can made a new comment: $activity->comment";
    if ($activity->type == 'post)
        echo "User has made a new post: $activity->post";
}
```

I hope it makes sense. Basically, I want to combine all three tables as one and then make a show them in a foreach loop in a `Recent User Activity` page.

Please let me know wha you think the best practice for this is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would leverage Eloquent's polymorphic relationships for this. Essentially your three tables have one thing in common, in that they are all activities, or 'Activitiable' for lack of a better term. See: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations